# Unable to create new user in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have installed mongodb as per this guide

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-14-04

However I have no idea how to fetch the admin user/pass or even create it.

```
db.createUser { user: "username",pwd: "monkey123",roles: [{ role: "readWrite", db: "0" } ]}
```

and get

```
2015-11-19T14:18:52.867-0500 E QUERY    SyntaxError: Unexpected token      {
```

I follow the mongo docs and get this also

```
TypeError: Property 'addUser' of object 0 is not a function
```

All I want is to get the admin user/pass or make my own user so I can connect the nodebb forum app to mongodb.

Comment: Are you using coffeescript?

Comment: Should be enclosed in function `()` e.g. `db.createUser( { user: "username",pwd: "monkey123",roles: [{ role: "readWrite", db: "0" } ]} );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
db.createUser({user: "username", pwd: "monkey123", roles: [{role: "readWrite", db: "0"}]});
```

You missed the `()`.